# Starting Web Development and interactive experiences

Tags: jquery, asp.net, wpf, web-development

I'm new to web development and I'm a bit confused about the different languages and technologies in the web.
I understand the basic is Html, Javascript, and Css.
Then there's jQuery, ASP.net, Html5.
I'm confused where I should use each technology and which should I use.
For example, here is a video of a WPF application that I built:

[WPF app demo](http://www.screencast.com/t/OTS7tZecA)

The app is essentially for students, teaching some lessons. The student can choose a lesson, and listen and see images. The student can also test himself. As you can see, the app has some animation and stlying
If I were to attempt at building this application for the web- where should I start from and what should I use? HTML5 (Canvas?), jQuery (jQueryUI?), ASP.net?

I would really appreciate it if you can help me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick overview:

- HTML is your mark up language. This is how you render the basic content (I believe its similar to XAML). This is where you define the content
- CSS is your styling language. Here you defines what styles to apply to elements. This is where you define the look and feel of your application.
- JavaScript is the client side scripting language. This is where you manipulate html in the browser. It's used for events, animations and general ui wizardy.

As for ASP.NET it's just a server-side implementation. There are many (django, RoR, PHP, node.js, etc, etc).

As for jQuery it's a library for JavaScript that gives you free cross-browser support and jQuery  UI is a UI library written for jQuery that makes it easier to place UI elements on your page.

HTML5 is a buzzword for the latest HTML based techniques. There are many of these and they a re varied. [The modernizr download page](http://www.modernizr.com/download/) shows a nice overview of HTML5 features.

HTML5 Canvas is a way to place a grid on the screen you can render to through pixel manipulation.

Comment: I see. Thanks for clearing that up. So where should I start if I want to build that app in the web?

Comment: @amitairos if your interested in any specific technology feel free to ask.

Comment: @Raynos I'm trying to understand how to build interactive web experiences like the app in the video. Where should I start from and what should I learn?

Comment: @amitairos [Learn html/css/js](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn) [Learn ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/samples/mvc-music-store) [Learn Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/)

Comment: @Raynos thanks. What is the Learn Raphael and how will it help me? Also, should I/Do I have to- use ASP.net (or other server side languages) for this? Why?

Comment: @Amitairos. Raphael is an SVG wrapper. It allows you to draw shapes on the screen easily that you can manipulate. It's an easy way to quickly mock a UI together. You need a server for persistant storage (a database) and _security_.

Comment: @Raynos What would I use Raphael for in the above WPF example?

Comment: @arnitairos it's an alternative to jQuery and jQuery UI for making the interface and the animations.

Comment: @Raynos And how would this integrate with CSS? Or is that for a different purpose?

Comment: CSS styles HTML not SVG. CSS can be used with HTML and jQuery. there is a large range of UI toolkits btw, extJS, mochaui, smartclient to name a few.

Comment: @Raynos Ok. So where in the application would I want to use Css, and where SVG?

Comment: @amitairos they don't really overlap much. CSS is for statically styling content. Raphael is for making dynamic content. It's a design choice to use these tools. You don't need SVG or the canvas, it's merely another option.

Comment: @Raynos Ok. Thanks a bunch. I'll start learning and see where I get to.

Comment: @amitairos ignore raphael for now. Both the music store and the mozilla network are solid places to learn html/js/css/mvc.

Comment: @Raynos Should I learn jQuery too as an extension/replacement to Javascript?

Comment: @arnitairos you might aswell. the ASP.NET MVC tutorial will use some jQuery. search SO for good jQuery learning resources.